# Is this a green Wandering Jew plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I think I may have inherited two of these green wandering Jew plants... but I can’t find any description of the tiny white flowers that it’s putting off... does anyone have any pics of this variety of jew’s flowers?

[image]

Comment: How fast do they grow? The wandering Jew that I had, which looked like yours (although I never got flowers) grew quite fast in a south window, and was easy to root in water quickly.

Answer (score 1):

[wandering jew flower](https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2907/14341729852_b07ca2eb16_b.jpg)

Your plant most certainly looks like a wandering jew...it could also be a few other plants...really need more information about this plant.  Looks like you've used potting soil in that pot, is that right?

What window is supplying the light?  How close is this plant to the window?  How are you watering?  How about fertilizer?  How was this plant taken care of before you became caretaker?  It looks healthy but you'll need to give it fertilizer after a while and it is good to know what this plant is used to getting.  Is it in its original soil?  Or did you transplant it, them?

Wandering Jew looks like to me...is this your first house plant?

White flower is normal, that flower should develop into the flower pics I sent...

Comment: It looks like the kind I used to have. What other plants did you have on mind, stormy?

Comment: baby salal?  not remembering the name at all but depending on the scale, this could be the...minor salal?  There is another one that is actually a plant for aquariums that has been let loose somewhere...does fine in bogs...I have babied a purple dark violet purple wandering jew, propagated it for friends, that was breath taking.

Comment: Bulbs or corms? Little blue flowers? I've a 30's groundcover run wild that looks a lot like your photo. If so, dig the stuff up, or it will soon be everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty certain that's a variety of wondering jew.  They like plenty of light and water, you can also root from cuttings in water.  One thing to caution you on, they are an invasive plant, if planted outdoors in warm climates, they tend to take over.